# Slow transfer speeds on Synology DS2413+ with Windows over wifi only

Tags: windows, file-transfer, synology

I am using a Synology DiskStation DS2413+ in a mixed OS environment. It is connected via 2 ethernet cables to our n router (Asus, will update with details). When I mount the NAS via smb to an OS X 10.10.x box, transfer speeds are as advertised (something on the order of 50 MB/s over wifi lan). When I have a Windows 7 box connected through the standard Windows networking via ethernet to the router, I also get fast transfers. CloudStation transfers are also fast on both of these machines.

On another Windows 7 machine, which has no problem with fast internet via its wireless n card through our lan, we are experiencing excruciatingly slow transfer speeds to the nas (2 MB/s peak). This machine is slow over both CloudStation and Windows networking but again is fast for everything else. What could be causing slow wireless transfers to Windows with the nas?

Any help is greatly appreciated; happy to provide complete technical details if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds normal, 2MB/s is around 16mbps. It does seem slow, however it is over a WiFi connection. I'd look at your link speed; if that's high maybe your wifi router doesn't have the capacity to allow for high speed wireless, maybe look at investing in a decent router.

Comment: It is not inherently a problem of the router, as the OS X speeds over wifi are much higher.

Comment: @hodgkin-huxley ah, my mistake. Well, the mac will most likely be using AFP and Windows SMB, but otherwise i'm a little lost. My only thought is the WiFi card. It may only have 1x1 MIMO or could be operating on g. It's possible that it could just be an old card too.